# How to disable blue/green rectangle on fancybox popup image?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

The problem is on the following page:
http://stanok-by.ru/site/index.php/stanok-01

Joomla Simple Image Gallery plugin uses fancybox library. While clicking on a small image a large one pops up. When I hover mouse cursor on right or left side of large image there appears a blue rectangle closing part of the image. How to turn off this rectangle?

As I understood, this element corresponds to following HTML tag defined in file jquery.fancybox.js:

<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"></a>

So, there are following common Joomla css rules for "a" links from this css file:
http://stanok-by.ru/site/templates/beez_20/css/personal.css

```
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus
{
    background:#095197;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

How can I deprecate these rules for fancybox? Can I write somewhere in it:

```
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus
{
    background:none;
}
```

Or it will not work as it does not now?

Expected:
Blue rectangle not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any blue rectangle, but I guess that it is an outline and you can disable that using smth like `a:focus { outline: none}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by adding following code:

To .js file:

```
<a id="a-fancybox-next" title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

To .css file:

```
#a-fancybox-next
{
    background: none;
}
```

How can I contribute this fix to Simple Image Gallery plugin distributive for Joomla?